# How to safely remove www pool and default site from nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

As you know when you install nginx, it comes with default pool called `www` and a default site called `default`.

How can I safely remove these two? Because I have created a new pool and site and I want to release some resources by deleting these.

Comment: Did you try going to sites-enabled and delete the symlink to default?

Comment: Nginx does not have pools. Are you referring to PHP pools? In general with Nginx if you want to remove a site defined in its own file you just delete the file and restart.

Comment: Yeah sorry I am talking about php-fpm pools.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file locations and service names might be a bit different, but you just need to delete the two configs and reload:

1. Delete the pool configuration file `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf`
2. Delete the default site configuration file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and its symlink `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`
3. Reload nginx `sudo service nginx reload`
4. Reload fpm `sudo service php7.0-fpm reload`

Comment: You can leave the configuration file in sites-available, since it won't be enabled unless it's linked to sites-enabled.  Up to you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also leave `www.conf` as a template for later use:

1. `mv /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.template`
2. `sudo service php7.0-fpm reload`

This way default config is still present and can be used as a template for other pool configurations. The file itself won't be used to create a php pool as it does not meet the `include` directive in `/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf`:

`include=/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/*.conf`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to remove default ngnix file only and not php pool, then you can follow this answer. I am writing this assuming the server as ubuntu. Files location may be a little different for different machines. You just need to remove default server configuration from sites-available and sites-enabled. Follow these instructions :

1. Go to sites-enabled by `sudo cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.
2. Delete the link to default file `sudo rm -f default`.
3. Go to sites-available by `sudo cd /etc/nginx/sites-available`.
4. Delete the file default by `sudo rm -f default`.
5. Reload ngnix to check if everything is alright and make your change to come into effect by `sudo nginx -t && nginx -s reload`

If it does not show any error, proves entries done by you have been accepted and you have removed the default server file done by ngnix.